# Get null values in apex trigger and class when insert in SObject

Tags: apex, trigger

i have create following class.

```
public class MDLiveIntegration {       

public static String name;
public static String fname;
public static String lname;
public static String Product_Bunndle;
public static String Account_name;
public static String Opps_name;
public static String email;
public static String city;
public static String state;
public static String country;
public static String code;
public static String street;  
public static String phone;
public static String ID;
public static String myIds;
public static String gen;
public static Date bdate;
public static String ext_Id;

public MDLiveIntegration(){
}

public void contactValue(List<Subscriber__c> items){

    for(Subscriber__c sub : items){

        Contact c = [Select id, name, gender__c, Phone,FirstName, LastName,MailingCity, MailingState, MailingCountry,MailingPostalCode, MailingStreet,Email,Birthdate from Contact where Id =: sub.Subscriber_Contact__c];
        System.debug('Name:'+c.name);
        name = c.name;
        fname = c.FirstName;
        lname = c.LastName;
        Product_Bunndle = sub.Product_Bundle__c;
        Account_name = sub.Subscriber_Account__c;
        Opps_name = sub.Related_Opportunity__c;
        email = c.email;            
        street = c.MailingStreet;
        city = c.MailingCity;
        state = c.MailingState;
        code = c.MailingPostalCode;
        country = c.MailingCountry;
        phone = c.phone;
        myIds = sub.id;
        gen = c.gender__c;
        bdate = c.Birthdate;
        ext_id = sub.id;


        System.debug('Name:'+name);   
        System.debug('First Name:'+fname);         
        System.debug('Last Name:'+lname);                        
        System.debug('Product Bunndle:'+Product_Bunndle);   
        System.debug('Account Name:'+Account_name);         
        System.debug('Opportunity Name:'+Opps_name);
        System.debug('Email :'+email);
        System.debug('City :'+city);                                    
        System.debug('State :'+state);                                    
        System.debug('Country :'+country);                                    
        System.debug('Postal Code:'+code);                                    
        System.debug('Street :'+street);                                    
        System.debug('Birthday :'+bdate);  
    }
}

@future(callout=true)
public static void insertSubs(Id ids){

public static String username = '5uhhyakk75588';
public static String password = '7899555yYYoooY';
public static String jsonData;
public static HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();  

    System.debug('Fname'+fname);
    System.debug('Lname'+lname);
    System.debug(' B Date ' +  bdate );
    Date test = Date.valueOf(bdate);
    System.debug(' Next Date ' +  bdate );

    req.setEndpoint('https://demo-members.mdlive.com/services/members');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username +':' +password);
    String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);

    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
    req.setHeader('RemoteUserId', '596be46df99cb0c3348a');

    jsonData = '{"member":{"external_id":' + '\"'+ ext_id +'\"'+',"first_name":' + '\"'+ fname +'\"'+',"last_name":'+'\"'+ lname +'\"'+',"address1":'+'\"' + street + '\"'+',"gender":'+'\"'+gen+'\"'+',"state":'+'\"'+state+'\"'+',"zip":'+'\"'+code+'\"'+',"City":'+'\"'+city+'\"'+',"Country":'+'\"'+country+'\"'+',"Email":'+'\"'+email+'\"'+',"Phone":'+'\"'+phone+'\"'+',"birthdate":'+'\"'+bdate+'\"'+'}}';
    req.setBodyAsBlob(Blob.valueof(jsondata));         

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug(res.getBody());

    // JSon parse for Id
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME){
            String fieldName = parser.getText();
            parser.nextToken();
            if(fieldName == 'Id'){
                ID = parser.getText();
            }
        }            
    }
    Subscriber__c mysubs = [Select id, name from Subscriber__c where Id =: ids];
    System.debug('Value of ids:'+ID);
    System.debug('Value of subs id'+mysubs.Id);
    System.debug('Value of name :'+mysubs.name);
    mysubs.Subscriber_Id__c = ID;
    update mysubs;  

} 

}
```

### Trigger

```
trigger SubscriberUpdateTrigger on Subscriber__c (after Insert, after Update, after delete) {


for(Subscriber__c subs : Trigger.new){           
    if(subs.Active_Subscriber__c == true){

        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            new MDLiveIntegration().contactValue(Trigger.new);    

            if(system.isFuture()) 
               return;

            MDLiveIntegration mdInsert = new MDLiveIntegration();

            MDLiveIntegration.insertSubs(subs.Id);                
        }
     }
}     
}
```

when i tried to insert value using "insertSubs" method. I don't get any value of fname, lname, email etc in my InsertSubs method. Any suggestions.

Thanks
Vimal

Comment: my problem is i get value in of fname in contactValue and stored in public static String fname variable and then tried to access in insertSubs. But not getting. I need that value in insertSubs().

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the @future method runs, the only values it has access to are the values from its argument list i.e. the one ID value. This is because a new instance of the class is used "in the future" and that means all the static and non-static fields of the class will start out null. But the platform preserves the method arguments for use "in the future".

In your code, you could pass the JSON string as second argument into the future method (e.g. return it from `contactValue`), so that the JSON is prepared in a context where all the values are available.

Incidentally, your code has an unconventional mix of static and non-static logic, perhaps in your attempt to get this working. It would be worth cleaning that up too.

**PS**

This is what I'm suggesting. Trigger:

```
trigger SubscriberUpdateTrigger on Subscriber__c (after Insert, after Update,
        after delete) {
    for (Subscriber__c sub : Trigger.new) {           
        if (subs.Active_Subscriber__c && sub.Subscriber_Contact__c != null) {
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                MDLiveIntegration md = new MDLiveIntegration();  
                String jsonData = md.createJson(sub);
                md.insertSubs(sub.Id, jsonData);
            }              
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class MDLiveIntegration {       
    public void createJson(Subscriber__c sub) {
        Contact c = [Select ... from Contact where Id = :sub.Subscriber_Contact__c];
        String jsonData = '{"member":...;
        return jsonData;
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public void insertSubs(Id id, String jsonData) {

        String username = '5uhhyakk75588';
        String password = '7899555yYYoooY';

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://demo-members.mdlive.com/services/members');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username +':' +password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        req.setHeader('RemoteUserId', '596be46df99cb0c3348a');
        req.setBodyAsBlob(Blob.valueof(jsondata));

        HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);

        String returnedId = null;
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME){
                String fieldName = parser.getText();
                parser.nextToken();
                if(fieldName == 'Id'){
                    returnedId = parser.getText();
                }
            }            
        }
        update new Subscriber__c(Id = id, Subscriber_Id__c = returnedId);
    }
}
```

Comment: no this is not working for me. I have take value from salesforce not from JSON string.

Comment: @VimalMakwana I've posted some code that hopefully makes clearer what I mean.